# Material node tree missing on scripting output

Tags: python, texturing, materials

I am trying to check material nodes on a mesh with Python scripting. I was using a [Iridescence material](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/blob/master/2.0/IridescenceLamp/glTF-Binary/IridescenceLamp.glb). In this material, there are two different output nodes named "Material Output" and "gltf Material Output". With scripting I can check "Material Output" node but I could not able to achieve "gltf Material Output". How can I check this node exist in material?

Script:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.data.objects["lamp_transmission"]
material_slots = obj.material_slots
for m in material_slots:
    material = m.material
    print("slot", m, "material", material)
    inputs = material.node_tree.nodes
    for i in inputs:
        print(i.type)
```

Output:
[image]

Material:
[image]

Comment: Try `print(i.name)` It's outputting "Group" because that's it type, not it's name.

Comment: Same output when I tried to print i.name

Comment: Try `i.label`......

Comment: Side note, in shader jargon *inputs* refers to the little dots on the left of the nodes which are used for linking to the *outputs* on the right of other nodes , naming the nodes `inputs`  is very confusing :)

Comment: @Psyonic I can not achieve "gltf Material Output" node even with "i.label".

Comment: @Gorgious Totally agreed :)

Comment: Please provide your blend file in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bpy

object = bpy.data.objects["lamp_transmission"]

if object.material_slots:
    for slot in object.material_slots:
        if slot.material and slot.material.use_nodes:
            for node in slot.material.node_tree.nodes:
                if node.type == 'GROUP' and node.node_tree.name == 'gltf Material Output':
                    print(node)
```